# How to retrieve features after PCA-LDA classification in matlab?

Tags: matlab, classification, pca, feature-extraction, lda

I need to classify spectral data, e.g. FTIR spectra, into three groups using LDA.

My data is high dimensional (451 dimensions == 451 wavenumbers) and strongly correlated. I mean, the value in one dimension is not independent of the other dimensions. Most of dimensions contains useful information, but only a few of them will be responsible by the separation into the three groups. I know that because it's possible to look at the raw data and to have an idea about which features are eligible to be the discriminant ones (I can have an idea but I cannot be sure just looking on it).

To solve my problem I combined PCA with LDA: I used PCA on the raw data to decorrelate it and also to reduce its dimensionality. Then I chose certain number of principal components (I have ways to choose them) and I classified the scores using LDA. It works pretty fine to me!

Now I would like to know which features (or dimensions or wavenumbers) where responsible by the LDA classification. On other words, I need to look at the raw data and know which dimensions are responsible by the differentiation between the three groups.

Thank you in advance for some help.

(I'm sorry if I posted my question in the wrong place. Please feel free to move it if applicable.)

Fabricio

Comment: As far as my understanding goes, when you apply PCA you change the bases of the system and lose the physical meaning of the variables. To identify which raw data feature is responsible for most of the variability I would try to apply other method, such as mutual information,which measures the similarity between signals

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your comment. I'm afraid that you are right... Let's see if other people agree as well. Thank you again and happy holidays!